# R how to pass NULL for optional parameters to function (e.g. in for loop)

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I wrote a for loop to test different settings for an ordination function in R (package "vegan", called by "phyloseq"). I have several subsets of my data within a list (`sample_subset_list`) and therefore, testing different parameters for all these subsets results in many combinations.

The ordination function contains the optional argument `formula` and I would like to perform my ordinations with and without a formula. I assume `NULL` would be the correct way to not use the `formula` parameter? But how do I pass `NULL` when using a for loop (or apply etc)?

Using the phyloseq example data:

```
library(phyloseq)
data(GlobalPatterns)
ps <- GlobalPatterns
ps1 <- filter_taxa(ps, function (x) {sum(x > 0) > 10}, prune = TRUE)
ps2 <- filter_taxa(ps, function (x) {sum(x > 0) > 20}, prune = TRUE)
sample_subset_list <- list()
sample_subset_list <- c(ps1, ps2)
```

I tried:

```
formula <- c("~ SampleType", NULL)

> formula
[1] "~ SampleType"

ordination_list <- list()
    for (current_formula in formula) {
                            tmp <- lapply(sample_subset_list, 
                                          ordinate, 
                                          method = "CCA",
                                          formula = as.formula(current_formula))
                            ordination_list[[paste(current_formula)]] <- tmp
}
```

this way, `formula` only consists of "~ SampleType". If I put NULL into ticks, it gets wrongly interpreted as formula:

```
formula <- c("~ SampleType", "NULL")
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)
```

What is right way to solve this?

Regarding Lyzander's answer:

```
# make sure to use (as suggested)
formula <- list("~ SampleType", NULL)
# and not 
formula <- list()
formula <- c("~ SampleType", NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `list` instead:

```
formula <- list("~ my_constraint", NULL)

# for (i in formula) print(i)
#[1] "~ my_constraint"
#NULL
```

If your function takes `NULL` as an argument for a function you should also do:

```
ordination_list <- list()
for (current_formula in formula) {
  tmp <- lapply(sample_subset_list, 
                ordinate, 
                method = "CCA",
                formula = if (is.null(current_formula)) NULL else as.formula(current_formula))
  ordination_list[[length(ordination_list) + 1]] <- tmp
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I still got the same error after using a list for your first suggestion. I assume your edit would solve this, but it breaks at the if statement. I also tried to break the lines with {} but it still returns ``Error: unexpected symbol in:
"formula = if(is.null(current_formula)) NULL else as.formula(current_formula ordination_list"`

Comment: Sorry I missed the bracket before `ordination_list`. Updated now. I cannot run your `lapply` unfortunately.

Comment: now it works for the second solution (with the if else condition), you maybe want to remove the first one? I also added example data. What is the reason for using `[[length(list)+1]]`? Thank you very much!

Comment: The reason for this is because you cannot name the element of the list as NULL as it will return an error. So you need to use the index.